Definition of smooth map between smooth manifolds
Let $(M,\mathcal{A})$ an m-dimensional smooth manifold and $(N, \mathcal{B})$ a n-dimensional smooth manifold, with $\mathcal{A}:=\{\phi_i:U_i\to V_i \ | \ i \in I\}$ an atlas for $M$ (that is: $U_i \subseteq M$ and $V_i \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$ are open sets, $\phi$ is an omeomorphism and the maps $\phi_\alpha\phi_\beta^{-1}$ are $C^{\infty}$)  and $\mathcal{B}:=\{\psi_i:W_j\to Z_j \ | \ j \in J\}$ an atlas for $N$.
A function $f:(M,\mathcal{A}) \to (N,\mathcal{B})$ is smooth if

$\forall p \in M, \ \exists U_i \in \mathcal{A} \  \exists W_j \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $p\in U_i, \ f(p) \in W_j$ and $f(U_i) \subseteq W_j$
The composition $\psi_j \circ f \circ \phi_i^{-1}$ is $C^{\infty}$

The problem is that a manifold is usually defined as $(M, [\mathcal{A}])$ where $[\mathcal{A}]$ is the equivalence class of all smooth atlas equivalent to $\mathcal{A}$ (two atlas $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{A'}$ are equivalent if $\mathcal{A} \cup \mathcal{A'}$ is an atlas).
Is the definition of smooth function independent of the choice of equivalent atlas?
Let $\mathcal{A'}$ equivalent to $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B'}$ equivalent to $\mathcal{B}$, I can't find $U'_i \in \mathcal{A'}$ and $W'_j \in \mathcal{B'}$ such that $p\in U'_i, \ f(p) \in W'_j$ and $f(U'_i) \subseteq W'_j$. Can you give me suggestions of what should i choose as $U'_i$ and $W'_j$?

Yes it is independent of the specific atlas used. What did you try to do to prove it?

ok i clarified the definitions and i specified where i'm stuck

try to start by "translating" what independence of the choice of an atlas from the equivalence class means in this case - if $p \in U_i$ and $p \in U_i^\prime$, what can be said about the intersection? What about the charts that belong to these neighborhoods?

You are right @AnneBauval, this can be solved by restricting the chart $\phi$ to $U\cap f^{-1}(W)$, this way you do not have to talk about a maximal atlas.

@AnneBauval this is the definition my professor gave during his lectures, are there other definitions of smooth maps?

Since differentiability in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is only dependent on the behaviour of the map on an arbitrarily small neighborhood, most of the authors only require the existence of an open neighborhood of $p$ and $f(p)$ which is a subset of a coordinate neighborhood of the respective atlas (or to define it for a maximal atlas, which contains all such neighborhoods as coordinate neighborhoods)

@AnneBauval ok with this new definition you gave me it all makes sense.

There are many posts on MSE about the definition(s) of smooth maps between manifolds. Does this one answer your question? Clarification on definition of smooth map between smooth manifolds
Your definition cannot be correct, unless "atlas" rather means here "maximal atlas". Otherwise, there often won't exist $U∈\mathcal A,W∈\mathcal B$ such that $f(U)⊆W$, although we want to accept $f$.
Another way to make your definition reasonable, is to just replace $∃U_i∈\mathcal A,∃W_j∈\mathcal B$ with $∃(U,ϕ)$ compatible with $\mathcal A$, $∃(W,ψ)$ compatible with $\mathcal B$, where $(U,ϕ)$ is said to be compatible with $\mathcal A$ if $\mathcal A∪\{(U,ϕ)\}$ is still an atlas. This way, all you need to check is that this compatibility only depends on the equivalence class.

Suppose $f$ is differentiable with respect to the atlases $\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}$. Then for all $p\in M$, there exist charts $(\tilde{U},\phi) \in \mathcal{A}$ and $(\tilde{V},\psi) \in \mathcal{B}$ and open neighborhoods $p \in U\subset \tilde{U}$ and $f(p) \in V\subset \tilde{V}$ such that $$f(U) \subset V$$ (this can be guaranteed by picking $U\cap f^{-1}(V)$ as the open neighborhood of $p$. This set is open since $f$ is continuous by definition) and further $$(\psi\circ f\circ\phi^{-1})_{|\phi(U)}\colon \phi(U)\to \psi(V)$$ is differentiable as a map between open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$.
Now let $\mathcal{A}^\prime$ and $\mathcal{B}^\prime$ be atlases in the same equivalency class as the respective atlases above. Then, for all charts $(U^\prime,\phi^\prime) \in \mathcal{A}^\prime$ around $p$ and $(V^\prime,\psi^\prime) \in \mathcal{B}^\prime$ around $f(p)$ we know that
$$\phi\circ (\phi^\prime)^{-1}\colon \phi^\prime(U\cap U^\prime)\to\phi(U\cap U^\prime)\text{ and }\psi^\prime \circ \psi^{-1}\colon \psi(V\cap V^\prime) \to \psi^\prime(V\cap V^\prime)$$ are smooth maps of open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$ respectively. These are
Note that these maps are also smooth when restricted to open subsets of these domains (since differentiability is defined via the existence of certain limits)
If we now concatenate the map $\psi\circ f\circ\phi^{-1}$, which shows differentiability with respect to $\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}$ with the transition maps that show compatibility of the atlases $\mathcal{A}^\prime,\mathcal{B}^\prime$, $\phi\circ (\phi^\prime)^{-1}$ from the right, and $\psi^\prime \circ \psi^{-1}$ from the left and restrict to the allowed domains, we arrive at
$$(\psi^\prime\circ \psi^{-1})\circ (\psi \circ f\circ\phi^{-1})\circ(\phi\circ(\phi^\prime))^{-1}_{|\phi^\prime(U\cap U^\prime)}=\psi^\prime\circ f\circ (\phi^\prime)^{-1}\colon \phi^\prime(U\cap U^\prime)\to \psi^\prime(V\cap V^\prime)$$
Which is smooth as a concatenation of smooth maps (all domains are open subsets of neighborhoods on which we know the maps to be smooth, this is something you should check for yourself).
Now $U\cap U^\prime$ and $V\cap V^\prime$ are neighborhoods which fulfill the definition of smoothness with respect to the atlases $\mathcal{A}^\prime,\mathcal{B}^\prime$. This shows that differentiability with respect to one choice of equivalent atlases implies differentiability with respect to every other choice, thus independence of the choice.
